# Change alternative colour of TR in multiple TBODY

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change alternative color of all TR which resides multiple TBODY. My html code is like as following.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Customer</th><th>Order</th><th>Month</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to set alternative color as following mode.

```
<table>
        <tbody>
          <tr> [ODD][Red]
          <tr> [EVEN][Green]
          <tr> [ODD][Red]
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr> [EVEN][Green]
          <tr> [ODD][Red]
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr> [EVEN][Green]
          <tr> [ODD][Red]
          <tr> [EVEN][Green]
        </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried so many example on StackOverFlow but my scenario is not matching. Following is the link which I have tried.

[Achieve alternate row colours across multiple tbody elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329493/achieve-alternate-row-colours-across-multiple-tbody-elements)

I need to use only CSS and Javascript [Not jquery]. please suggest how to achieve this.

thanks

Comment: If you want to do this with pure CSS, you'll need to remove the multiple `tbody` containers. CSS `:nth-child(odd)` and `even` only applies to children of a direct parent.

Comment: you could use something like: `tbody:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}`

Comment: I'm struggling to see why you'd want to do this from a semantics perspective. To have a striped design like this would imply that each table row is uniquely different from the next, but the use of multiple `<tbody>` elements implies that the data is in fact grouped and not unique in this way. Why do you have multiple `<tbody>` elements in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use plain javascript to do this. To select all `tr` you can use `querySelectorAll()` and then you can use `%` operator to check if `i` is even or odd. You can also start loop from 1 to ignore that first row in `thead`

```js
var tr = document.querySelectorAll('tr')
for(var i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
  tr[i].style.color = i % 2 ? 'red' : 'green';
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Customer</th><th>Order</th><th>Month</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using only CSS it is impossible in your scenario.

But, using Javascript you can iterate through all `<tr>` regardless in which `tbody` it is contained. And, add a class only to the even ones...

```js
var trs = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
for(var i=0; i<trs.length; i++) {
  if(i % 2 == 0)
    trs[i].className = "even";
}
```

```css
tbody tr {
  color: red;
}

tbody tr.even {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Customer</th><th>Order</th><th>Month</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using a javascript loop.

```js
var els = document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName("tr");

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    els[i].style.background = "red"
  } else {
    els[i].style.background = "green"
  }

}
```

```html
<table id='table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer</th>
      <th>Order</th>
      <th>Month</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 1</td>
      <td>#1</td>
      <td>January</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 1</td>
      <td>#3</td>
      <td>March</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 2</td>
      <td>#1</td>
      <td>January</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 2</td>
      <td>#2</td>
      <td>April</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 2</td>
      <td>#3</td>
      <td>March</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 3</td>
      <td>#1</td>
      <td>January</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 3</td>
      <td>#2</td>
      <td>April</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use JavaScript to add alternate classes to the rows. Pure CSS won't work since you're using multiple `tbody` containers.

```js
var evenrow = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('#table tr')
 .forEach(function(row) {
   if (evenrow) {
        row.className += ' red';
    } else {
        row.className += ' green';
    }
    evenrow = !evenrow;
  })
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Customer</th><th>Order</th><th>Month</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```